# VUE i18n not able to translate error messages

Tags: vue.js, locale, translation, vue-i18n

I have added the VUE i18n module to handle the translations locally and it is working fine. Now I want to translate the error messages which I'm receiving from the backend.
My configurations are

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

function loadLocaleMessages () {
const locales = require.context('./locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i)
const messages = {}
locales.keys().forEach(key => {
const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i)
if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
  const locale = matched[1]
  messages[locale] = locales(key)
}
})
return messages
}

export default new VueI18n({
 locale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_LOCALE || 'en-GB',
 fallbackLocale: process.env.VUE_APP_I18N_FALLBACK_LOCALE || 'en-GB',
 messages: loadLocaleMessages()
 })
```

I'm hitting an API and able to translate the message in the response of that API. Can anyone help me in this. Thanks

Comment: Assuming your API returns the same keys that are present in your `locales/en.js` file - you can simply call `this.$t(the_key_of_the_error)`

Comment: @IVOGELOV yes it returns the same key but I'm translating the response in a js file which is outside of components. Its helper.js

Comment: Then in your `helpers.js` you have to import the file which contains the code shown in your question - thus you will have access to the VueI18n instance.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Done that already. It is working if I'm calling i18n.t('logout_successFully') but it is not working if I'm translating it in api response i.e. api().then(reponse=> { i18n.t(response.message) })

Comment: You should check whether `response.message` is `logout_successFully` or something else. Additionally, you may need to return the result of `i18n.t()` to the Promise.

Comment: @IVOGELOV yes response.message is logout_successFully. So in then block, I'm calling a method where I am sending the translated message and showing that message to the user (but the message is printed as it is without being translated). And What do you mean by this: you may need to return the result of i18n.t() to the Promise.

Comment: If the message is not translated there are only 2 possible causes - the string is missing from the localization, or there are no localizations loaded inside the given `i18n` instance. You can quickly check by `api.then(response => console.log(i18n.messages.en[response.message]))`

Comment: @IVOGELOV If I'm printing the instance (i18n) I can see the messages loaded with the correct value, But when I'm using this  `api.then(response => console.log(i18n.messages.en[response.message]) ` it is printing `undefined` on console

Comment: The conclusion is that either (1) there is no "en" inside `i18n.messages`, or (2) there is no `logout_successFully` inside `i18n.messages.en`

Comment: @IVOGELOV Okay thanks for your help and time.

Comment: You may put a breakpoint inside the function and inspect the `i18n` instance in the DevTools.